# Проверка вхождения времени (HH:mm) в указанный диапазон работает некорректно

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Код в примере неверно считает минуты: если выставить рабочие часы 09:00-18:12, то в 18:00 уже выводит `"ЗАКРЫТО"`.
Подскажите, как это исправить?

Скрипт с просторов интернета.

```js
// Находим и обрабатываем выходные дни
$(".calendarik").each(function() {
  let oWorkingHours = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
  });
  let sRest = $(oWorkingHours).text();
  if (!sRest || !/[а-яё0-9-:]/gi.test(sRest)) {
    $(this).append("<span class='rest'>00:00 - 00:00</span>");
  } else if (/Выходной/gi.test(sRest)) {
    $(oWorkingHours).replaceWith("<span class='rest'>00:00 - 00:00</span>");
  } else if (sRest.match(/(\d+)/gi)[0] == sRest.match(/(\d+)/gi)[2]) {
    $(oWorkingHours).replaceWith("<span class='rest'>00:00 - 00:00</span>");
  }
});

// Получаем текущую дату и элемент с текущим днём недели
let oCurrDate = new Date();
let oCurrDay = $(".calendarik").eq(oCurrDate.getDay() == 0 ? 6 : oCurrDate.getDay() - 1);

// Парсим в тексте элемента часы работы текущего дня
let aCurrPartTime = oCurrDay.text().match(/(\d+)/gi).map(string => parseInt(string));

// Получаем предыдущую дату и элемент с предыдущим днём недели
let oYestDate = new Date();
oYestDate.setDate(oYestDate.getDate() - 1);

let oYestDay = $(".calendarik").eq(oYestDate.getDay() == 0 ? 6 : oYestDate.getDay() - 1);

// Парсим в тексте элемента часы работы предыдущего дня
let aYestPartTime = oYestDay.text().match(/(\d+)/gi).map(string => parseInt(string));

// Получаем текущий час
let nHour = oCurrDate.getHours();

// Создаём блок для надписи о статусе
let oStatus = $('<span class="status">');

// Функция добавления статуса
function fStatus(oParent, oChild, bOpen) {
  if (bOpen) {
    oChild.css("color", "green").html("ОТКРЫТО");
  } else {
    oChild.css("color", "red").html("ЗАКРЫТО");
  }
  oParent.append(oChild);
}

//// Если текущий час попадает в рабочий промежуток, тогда
//// устанавливаем нужный текст с нужным цветом у нужного дня
if (aCurrPartTime[0] > aCurrPartTime[2]) {
  aCurrPartTime[2] += 24;
}

if (aYestPartTime[0] > aYestPartTime[2]) {
  if (nHour < aYestPartTime[2]) {
    fStatus(oYestDay, oStatus, true);
  } else if (nHour >= aYestPartTime[2] && nHour < aCurrPartTime[0]) {
    fStatus(oCurrDay, oStatus, false);
  } else {
    if (nHour >= aCurrPartTime[0] && nHour < aCurrPartTime[2]) {
      fStatus(oCurrDay, oStatus, true);
    } else {
      fStatus(oCurrDay, oStatus, false);
    }
  }
} else {
  if (nHour >= aCurrPartTime[0] && nHour < aCurrPartTime[2]) {
    fStatus(oCurrDay, oStatus, true);
  } else {
    fStatus(oCurrDay, oStatus, false);
  }
}

// Подсвечиваем текущий день недели
oCurrDay.addClass("current");

// Выделяем выходные дни
$(".calendarik .rest").text("Выходной");
```

```css
.calendarik {
  font: normal 18px "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: #555;
}

.current {
  color: #07e;
}

.rest {
  color: #fa0;
}

.status {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6.4em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font: bold 1em "Courier New", monospace;
  animation: pulse 1.8s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%,
  100% {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  25%,
  76% {
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-align: left;
  }
  26%,
  75% {
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  50% {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Понедельник: </b>09:00 - 18:12</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Вторник: </b>09:00 - 18:12</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Среда: </b>09:00 - 18:12</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Четверг: </b>09:00 - 18:12</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Пятница: </b>09:00 - 17:12</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Суббота: </b>09:00 - 15:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Воскресение: </b>09:00 - 15:00</li>
</ul>
```

Песочница: https://jsfiddle.net/hu4v1nsg/

Comment: у меня все работает как надо

Comment: можете сделать скриншот, сделайте так: сейчас 15:07 то Среда график до 15:30 и покажет что закрыто.

Comment: понятно, если работает до XX:YY часов, то в любое время после XX:00 будет показывать, что закрыто, независимо от YY.

Comment: а можно сделать так как я написал?

Comment: конечно же можно

Comment: Поможете сделать?